# I may have broken something in a custom mod

Tags: mods, starbound

I have created a new custom race for Starbound, but alas, I have no idea of how mods work.

The original download was of a default copy of the Human race files. I simply retextured them. But now, that leaves me in a little bit of disarray.

I have this string:
`"charGenTextLabels" : [ "SKIN COLOR", "HAIR STYLE", "SHIRT", "PANTS", "HAIR COLOR", "SHIRT COLOR", "PANTS COLOR", "LA", "PERSONALITY" ],`
I have removed the options for skin color and undy color. Will the mod still function without those options?